# After uninstalling and reinstalling mono my winforms app won't start

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, mono

I have this test program

```
namespace MonoWindowsFormsTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Build on Windows 8.1 with .NET 4.5.1 and VS2012

I open my cmd, and change the directory to my debug folder, then I run this command:

```
mono myapp.exe > error.txt
```

It gives me nothing. It does not start my program and the error.txt is empty.

I have this in my PATH:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Mono-3.2.3\bin
```

This is run with mono 3.3.0.

Acctually this worked 10 minutes ago, but I decided to update Mono to 3.2.4, but it looks like the Mono 3.2.4 is only for OS X because the update link in the download section of the mono project points to 3.2.3 when selecting the Windows platform. But I went on anyway and installed the downloaded mono package.

Is there anything I have forgotten to do because of this reinstall? Installing something, write some config?

I have tried to build and run this simple console app

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MonoConsoleTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("hellllo");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

and it runs just fine when I run it through mono.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one was a hard one, but I suddenly remembered it. Last time I installed Mono on Windows I changed the C:\Program Files (x86)\Mono-3.2.3\etc\mono\config file to hold this:

```
<configuration>
    <dllmap dll="i:cygwin1.dll" target="libc.so.6" os="!windows" />
    <dllmap dll="libc" target="libc.so.6" os="!windows"/>
    <dllmap dll="intl" target="libc.so.6" os="!windows"/>
    <dllmap dll="intl" name="bind_textdomain_codeset" target="libc.so.6" os="solaris"/>
    <dllmap dll="libintl" name="bind_textdomain_codeset" target="libc.so.6" os="solaris"/>
    <dllmap dll="libintl" target="libc.so.6" os="!windows"/>
    <dllmap dll="i:libxslt.dll" target="libxslt.so" os="!windows"/>
    <dllmap dll="i:odbc32.dll" target="libodbc.so" os="!windows"/>
    <dllmap dll="i:odbc32.dll" target="libiodbc.dylib" os="osx"/>
    <dllmap dll="oci" target="libclntsh.so" os="!windows"/>
    <dllmap dll="db2cli" target="libdb2_36.so" os="!windows"/>
    <dllmap dll="MonoPosixHelper" target="libMonoPosixHelper.so" os="!windows" />
    <dllmap dll="i:msvcrt" target="libc.so.6" os="!windows"/>
    <dllmap dll="i:msvcrt.dll" target="libc.so.6" os="!windows"/>
    <dllmap dll="sqlite" target="libsqlite.so.0" os="!windows"/>
    <dllmap dll="sqlite3" target="libsqlite3.so.0" os="!windows"/>
    <dllmap dll="libX11" target="libX11.so" os="!windows" />
    <dllmap dll="libcairo-2.dll" target="libcairo.so.2" os="!windows"/>
    <dllmap dll="libcairo-2.dll" target="libcairo.2.dylib" os="osx"/>
    <dllmap dll="libcups" target="libcups.so.2" os="!windows"/>
    <dllmap dll="libcups" target="libcups.dylib" os="osx"/>
    <dllmap dll="i:kernel32.dll">
        <dllentry dll="__Internal" name="CopyMemory" target="mono_win32_compat_CopyMemory"/>
        <dllentry dll="__Internal" name="FillMemory" target="mono_win32_compat_FillMemory"/>
        <dllentry dll="__Internal" name="MoveMemory" target="mono_win32_compat_MoveMemory"/>
        <dllentry dll="__Internal" name="ZeroMemory" target="mono_win32_compat_ZeroMemory"/>
    </dllmap>
    <dllmap dll="gdiplus" target="@prefix@/lib/libgdiplus@libsuffix@" os="!windows"/>
    <dllmap dll="gdiplus.dll" target="@prefix@/lib/libgdiplus@libsuffix@"  os="!windows"/>
    <dllmap dll="gtkhtml-3.0" target="libgtkhtml-3.8-15.dll"/>
</configuration>
```

I have made changes to these two lines

```
<dllmap dll="gdiplus" target="@prefix@/lib/libgdiplus@libsuffix@" os="!windows"/>
<dllmap dll="gdiplus.dll" target="@prefix@/lib/libgdiplus@libsuffix@"  os="!windows"/>
```

Adding **os="!windows"** according to this link: https://github.com/mono/mono/pull/587/files. When I run my windows forms app via mono it starts right away.

Comment: Accept your answer to close the topic.

Comment: I would if I could @Rolice, but Stackoverflow has a rule that I can only accept my own answer after a certain amount of time. So tomorrow I will accept my own answer.